# Microsoft Graph Post action to Create group "Bad request"

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to POST a request to the Microsoft Graph API to create a group, like explained [HERE](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_groups)

**The base url is:** https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
Content type is set to apllication/json
We have a valid Baerer token as well.

We are using the Group class from the Microsoft.Graph namespace (NuGet Package) so we populate the properties with our data and call the JsonConvert.SerializeObject(group) to serialize the group objecet to Json.

**This is how we build up and serialze:**

```
 Microsoft.Graph.Group group = new Microsoft.Graph.Group();
                group.Description = "Self help community for library";
                group.DisplayName = "Library Assist";
                group.GroupTypes = new[] { "Unified" };
                group.MailEnabled = true;
                group.MailNickname = "library";
                group.SecurityEnabled = true;

   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(group);

   var content = new StringContent(json);
   var response = httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync(Uri, content).Result;
```

**The headers of the HttpClient are set like this:**

```
 httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "...value of baerer token...");
 httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

We are building the URL up starting from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0`
adding `/groups` to it

In the response we are getting a `Bad request status code 400`.
This is implying that there is an error in the request URI, headers, or body but in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) the same code as above works fine, we get results in the response.
**What am i overseeing?**

Thank you for any feedback or suggestion.
Kind regards.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code sample? This implies you're serializing a string (`postBody`) but I assume that isn't really the case.

Comment: Hey @MarcLaFleur and thank you for taking a look. I have updated the original post. If i can clarify anything let me know. Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already using the `Microsoft.Graph` namespace, you can use built-in the `GraphServiceClient` to make request as below. You needn't use the http client or serialize objects, this will be handled :

```
var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        (requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", "<your-access-token>");              
        }));

var group = new Microsoft.Graph.Group
{
    DisplayName = "Library Assist",
    Description = "Self help community for library",
    MailNickname = "library",
    MailEnabled = true,
    SecurityEnabled = true,
    GroupTypes = new List<string> { "Unified" }
};      

var createdGroup = await graphserviceClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(group);
```

Reference - [Intro to the Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](http://www.jonathanhuss.com/intro-to-the-microsoft-graph-net-client-library/)

Comment: you saved our day! This works like expected! Thank you so much!